# Why mysqli escape single quote( ' ) during record fetch in php?

Tags: php, escaping

i am retrieving  record from table ' student '. where student name is saved like John's Mark. but when i am fetching record from table using

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs);
 echo $row['stu_name'] ;
```

Output :: John .

desired output should be like :: John's Mark

how can i get my result as i stored in table.
for information i m using this code for escape string...

```
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
                        {
                            $string = stripslashes($string);
                                }
                                    if (phpversion() >= '4.3.0')
                                        {  

                                      $string = mysqli_real_escape_string($mod_obj->myObj->cid,$string);  // only for 5.6 version.
                                  }
                            else
                        {

                    $string = mysql_escape_string($string);
                }
            return trim($string);
```

Comment: Are you sure the name is stored correctly in the DB?

Comment: yes ,i m sure about  john's mark... getting only john

Comment: I didn't ask that. I want to know, if you can proof, that the DB contains `John's Mark` instead of just `John`.

Comment: Are you outputting to an input field using single quotes for the value encapsulation? You also tagged 1064, which is a mysql syntax error, are you getting an error?

Comment: no not getting error 1064.. only for catch attention of people in this problem. there is no relation of 1064 to this problem.  but yes i am getting value in  input text.. this is happening in first time .so i m confuse what is going wrong... but for output i m not using any escape method. just echo

Comment: like echo " <input type='text ' name='' id='' value='$row[stu_name]' />"

Comment: i just checked ,it issue a problem when in using this into  <input type= 'text'/> else working fine ,,,

Comment: <input id="fname" class="form-control" name="fname" placeholder="Pankaj" maxlength="30"   value="Pankaj\"" kumar="" type="text"> it is breaking sting n quote.... result should be like Pankaj" kumar. but working fine in single quote ...

Comment: I think , i  have a solution of this problem .... that is , we need to convert every special type of symbol to HTML Character Entities. that will not cause any problem while retrieve row in input field or as plain text both case. i have tested in mysqli .. working fine.  ... by the way thanks paul u given me clue for solution...

Answer (score 0):

Forget about string escaping, magic quotes etc.
Use [parameter binding](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) instead.

Comment: Why do you use the stuff like mysql_escape_string etc? To prepare string before inserting/updating - convert quotes, carrier returns etc. -- escape all the special chars. Actually you can avoid it by using bind parameters to statement.

Comment: The quote is in the DB so binding wouldnt/isnt the issue.

Comment: I have a idea and it is best way to escape string into html entities... mostly single  quote and double quote.... then no need to prepare or build parameter ... yes it is good practice and working fast but make program little bit complex. and consume coding line...